whats the password after decrypting HG8546M. I cant remember the ISP web credentials
I am trying to get the web UI password of my Huawei ONT, model HG8546M.
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="1" UserName="root" Password="ae...49" UserLevel="1" Enable="1" ModifyPasswordFlag="0" PassMode="3" Salt="ef...42"/>
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="2" UserName="telecomadmin" Password="40...ef" UserLevel="0" Enable="1" ModifyPasswordFlag="0" PassMode="2"/>


Hi and welcome to RE.SE. And what is your question? You can use a search for Huawei or that plus "router" or the [tag:decryption] to find many similar requests. But neither is your non-question useful for future Internauts, nor would answers be that merely give you the password.
